# How do I know which button was clicked in ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have created a custom ListView adapter. In the `getView`, I have another override method `onClick`. My problem is how do I know which button in the ListView got clicked?

**item_category**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/specialCatItemName"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:text="View"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnSpecialView"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:background="#CCBA56"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:minHeight="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btnSpecialImages"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnSpecialImages"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"/>

    <Button
        android:text="Images"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnSpecialImages"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:background="#011E4D"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:minHeight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/specialCatItemName"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnSpecialView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btnSpecialView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Cursor Adapter**

```
 class categoryCursorAdaptor extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    String[] data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    int gPosition;
    String row;

    public categoryCursorAdaptor(Context context, String[] data) {
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return data[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        this.gPosition = position;
        this.row = data[position];
        if (vi == null) vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_category, null);
        TextView text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.specialCatItemName);
        text.setText(data[position]);

        Button Button1= (Button) vi.findViewById(R.id.btnSpecialView);
        Button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               //How do I know which button is got clicked?
            }
        });
        return vi;
    }
}
```

Comment: The first one. The Button1 var you have get the reference of the view from a ID which is btnSpecialView. If you want both buttons you need to use 2 variable. add: `Button Button2= (Button) vi.findViewById(R.id. btnSpecialImages);` so you can access the second button click

Comment: The position variable tells you the item number where the click took place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Devil Raily You can use setTag and getTag method to get the position. Use code like this

```
Button Button1= (Button) vi.findViewById(R.id.btnSpecialView);
Button1.setTag(position);
Button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override 
            public void onClick(View view) {
               //How do I know which button is got clicked? 
                int position = (Integer)view.getTag();
            } 
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Button Button1= (Button) vi.findViewById(R.id.btnSpecialView);
 Button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        if(gPosition ==1){
              // btn 2 was clicked 
         }
      else if(gPosition ==2){
          // btn 3 was clicked
        }
           // and so on

        }
    });
```

note that position value start from 0

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can implement View's OnClickListner in your activity...Override on click method.

```
Button b1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
b1.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Full Code to this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button b1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button b2= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Button b3= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    b1.setOnClickListener(this);
    b2.setOnClickListener(this);
    b3.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.button1 :
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"button1", 1000).show();
        break;
    case R.id.button2 :
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"button2", 1000).show();
        break;
    case R.id.button3 :
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"button3", 1000).show();
        break;  


    }

}
 }
```

Comment: Can you explain a little more clearly exactly what your doing there? :)

Comment: Sure, I am @Overriding the onCreate() and onClick() methods so i can get(on the onClick() method) the exactly button that was clicked by its ID. 

Only thing i did different was using a Toast to tell me which button was clicked. Clear enough? xD

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
 Button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           //How do I know which button is got clicked?
        }
    });
```

with:

```
 Button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           //How do I know which button is got clicked?
           onMyButtonClicked(position, view);
        }
    });
```

and implement

```
void onMyButtonClicked(int position, View view){
  //DoStuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to implement the click into your activity, when you set your adapter. Like this:

```
adapter = new categoryCursorAdaptor(yourListBase, this);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            adapter.getItem(position); // return the object from the position of your list

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

//How do I know which button is got clicked?

Add the following:

int clickedButton = view.getId();

switch(clickedButton) {

```
   case R.id.btnSpecialView : 

      // btnSpecialView is clicked - Do something break; 

      break;

   case R.id.btnSpecialImages : 

       // btnSpecialImages is clicked - Do something break;

       break;
```

}